# I have ADM ATHLON(tm) 64 x2 dual core. Should i install ubuntu

Tags: ati

I have a Amd athlom(tm) 64 x2 dual core processor 5200+ 2.71 GHz with 1 Gb Rm Running a fake licence of windows 7. But it is not running as good as I'd like. Should I install either 32 or 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS ?

Comment: Edit your title to make it more clear what you're asking. It sounds like you're asking "Is ubuntu good?"

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for Ubuntu tells you what hardware specs you need in order to install and run Ubuntu. Since Ubuntu requires less RAM than Windows, you probably have enough RAM.

Personally, I would not keep Windows and instead simply replace it entirely with Ubuntu since you may run into issues with the drive partitioning. If you absolutely need to run Windows 7, you can always install a Windows virtual machine (i.e. a vagrant box).

As to whether you need 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu, you can find out what your system is running by following the steps listed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/827218).

Answer (score 0):

1 G of ram is not enough to run ubuntu 14.04 here are [the minimal system requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME#Minimum_System_Requirements) 
you may consider lighter distros like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.